# Using UpdatePanel inside Splitter

Tags: asp.net

I added a splitter to my web page to split the page in two sections. Now, In the left panel, I would like to add a UpdatePanel to wrap several controls in the left panel only. I tried several placements options of the UpdatePanel, but the only working options (Meaning that when a SelectIndexChange takes place with ASPxComboBox1, the code behind update the content of ASPxComboBox2) is the attached code. However, I need to limit the wrapping of the UpdatePanel to the content of the first panel only (Left section of the splitter). What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> 

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <dx:ASPxSplitter ID="ASPxSplitter1" runat="server">
                        <Panes>
                            <dx:SplitterPane>
                                <ContentCollection>
                                    <dx:SplitterContentControl runat="server">
                                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server" ValueType="System.Int32" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" TextField="CategoryName" ValueField="CategoryID"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName] FROM [Categories]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox2" runat="server" ValueType="System.String"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                    </dx:SplitterContentControl>
                                </ContentCollection>
                            </dx:SplitterPane>

                            <dx:SplitterPane>
                                <ContentCollection>
                                    <dx:SplitterContentControl runat="server">
                                    </dx:SplitterContentControl>
                                </ContentCollection>
                            </dx:SplitterPane>

                        </Panes>
                    </dx:ASPxSplitter>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using the UpdatePanel only to "group" some controls?

Comment: I just use:  <div id="myContainer"> ... all my comboxes and labels </div>